# Dynamic template wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

i have made a template that look like this :

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="onoffValue" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <RadioButton Content="On" Height="20" Name="On_radiobutton" />
                <RadioButton Content="Off" Height="20" Name="Off_radiobutton" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BootSector}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="On_radiobutton" Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BootSector}" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="Off_radiobutton" Property="IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                </DataTrigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

For now, it is bind to the property BootSector(bool) ofa "Configuration" object.

I use this template in my window that has a configuration object as data context like this :

```
<Control Template="{StaticResource onoffValue}">

</Control>
```

It works great, but i want to go further.

I would like to know how i can pass a different property to my template to dynamically bind (dynamically change the property the template is bind to)
ie i tryed something like

```
<Control Template="{StaticResource onoffValue}" xmlns:test="{Binding Path=BootSector}"/>
```

and bind it in the template to "test" but it doesn't work

Is it possible ? How can i do that ? I think i'm not too far away but not there still !

Thank you in advance

Edit : Concerning Dmitry answer :
    There is a bug using that. When i do :

```
<StackPanel local:ToggleControl.IsOn="{Binding BootSector, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <RadioButton Content="On" local:ToggleControl.Role="On"  Height="20" Margin="5" />
                            <RadioButton Content="Off" local:ToggleControl.Role="Off" Height="20" Margin="5" />
                        </StackPanel>
```

By default BootSector is on false. When i click on the on button (true), it sets bootSector to true and then immediately to false . The behaviour should be that it stays to true until it is unchecked ? Is this related to the problem related here ? http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2008/10/17/125901.aspx

Comment: Your current template does not change "BootSector" when the user clicks the radio buttons. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: it is still a work in progress on that point,but i'm looking to do that too, if you have any input on that that would be great too

Comment: @djfoxmccloud How are you planning to use that 'Templated Template'? Say, you have it - how would you utilise it, could you post a sample here?

Comment: did you try the button? for it always returns correct values

Comment: @djfoxmccloud  = could you check if you don't have any custom logic in your BootSector property setter or other properties affecting BootSector's value? Put a break point in its setter and see where it gets called from for the second time? If you you take TwoBoolean and put a breakpoint on PropertyA & PropertyB setters - you'll see that they get called once and just once after a RadioButton is clicked. Just try switching to TwoBoolean class for a sec and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Ok this works ! After looking again at your code i found an artefact in mine that was causing a bad behaviour. Thank you for this ! Now i'll try to templatize this as a control template to pass the property as argument. So that i dont have to have to copy paste much xaml. Thank you very much, i thought it could be done easier !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the idea is - generic behaviors are never complex and generally not worth creating a custom control. I undertand that implmentation may vary, but the approach will remain the same. It makes sense to use XAML for the parts which can change and code for the stuff which will remain constant.

UPDATE 1- It's getting even easier when using Custom controls. You won't need attached property no more - as you'll get a dedicated space for it inside your custom control, also, you can use x:Name and GetTemplateChild(..) to otain a reference to individual RadioButtons.

```
Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace RadioButtons
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += (o, e) =>
            {
                this.DataContext = new TwoBoolean()
                {
                    PropertyA = false,
                    PropertyB = true
                };
            };
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((TwoBoolean)this.DataContext).ToString());
        }
    }

    public enum RadioButtonRole
    { 
        On,
        Off
    }


    public class ToggleControl : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOnProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsOn",
            typeof(bool?),
            typeof(ToggleControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback((o, e) => 
                {
                    ToggleControl.OnIsOnChanged((Panel)o, (bool)e.NewValue);
                })));


        public static readonly DependencyProperty RoleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Role",
            typeof(RadioButtonRole?),
            typeof(ToggleControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback((o, e) =>
                {

                })));

        private static readonly DependencyProperty IsSetUpProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSetUp",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ToggleControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(false));

        private static void OnIsOnChanged(Panel panel, bool e)
        {
            if (!ToggleControl.IsSetup(panel))
            {
                ToggleControl.Setup(panel);
            }

            RadioButtonRole role;

            if (e)
            {
                role = RadioButtonRole.On;
            }
            else
            {
                role = RadioButtonRole.Off;
            }

            ToggleControl.GetRadioButtonByRole(role, panel).IsChecked = true;
        }

        private static void Setup(Panel panel)
        {
            // get buttons
            foreach (RadioButton radioButton in
                new RadioButtonRole[2]
                {
                    RadioButtonRole.On, 
                    RadioButtonRole.Off
                }.Select(t =>
                    ToggleControl.GetRadioButtonByRole(t, panel)))
            {
                radioButton.Checked += (o2, e2) => 
                {
                    RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)o2;

                    panel.SetValue(ToggleControl.IsOnProperty, 
                        ToggleControl.GetRadioButtonRole(checkedRadioButton) == RadioButtonRole.On);
                };
            }

            panel.SetValue(ToggleControl.IsSetUpProperty, true);
        }

        private static bool IsSetup(Panel o)
        {
            return (bool)o.GetValue(ToggleControl.IsSetUpProperty);
        }

        private static RadioButton GetRadioButtonByRole(RadioButtonRole role,
            Panel container)
        {
            return container.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().First(t => 
                (RadioButtonRole)t.GetValue(ToggleControl.RoleProperty) == role);
        }

        private static RadioButtonRole GetRadioButtonRole(RadioButton radioButton)
        {
            return (RadioButtonRole)radioButton.GetValue(ToggleControl.RoleProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsOn(DependencyObject o, bool? e)
        {
            o.SetValue(ToggleControl.IsOnProperty, e);
        }

        public static bool? GetIsOn(DependencyObject e)
        {
            return (bool?)e.GetValue(ToggleControl.IsOnProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRole(DependencyObject o, RadioButtonRole? e)
        {
            o.SetValue(ToggleControl.RoleProperty, e);
        }

        public static RadioButtonRole? GetRole(DependencyObject e)
        {
            return (RadioButtonRole?)e.GetValue(ToggleControl.RoleProperty);
        }
    }

    public class TwoBoolean: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool propertyA, propertyB;

        public bool PropertyA
        {
            get
            {
                return this.propertyA;
            }
            set
            {
                this.propertyA = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("PropertyA");
            }
        }

        public bool PropertyB
        {
            get
            {
                return this.propertyB;
            }
            set
            {
                this.propertyB = value;

                this.OnPropertyChanged("PropertyB");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, 
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("PropertyA:{0}, PropertyB:{1}", this.PropertyA, this.PropertyB);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

}
```

Markup:

```
<Window x:Class="RadioButtons.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioButtons"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">PropertyA</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel local:ToggleControl.IsOn="{Binding PropertyA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <RadioButton Content="On" local:ToggleControl.Role="On"  Height="20" Margin="5" />
            <RadioButton Content="Off" local:ToggleControl.Role="Off" Height="20" Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">PropertyB</TextBlock>
        <StackPanel local:ToggleControl.IsOn="{Binding PropertyB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <RadioButton Content="On" local:ToggleControl.Role="On"  Height="20"  Margin="5" />
            <RadioButton Content="Off" local:ToggleControl.Role="Off" Height="20" Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Save</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an `xmlns` to pass a parameter, rather use the `Tag` or template a `ContentControl`, then you can bind the `Content` to your property (set it to `TwoWay`) and use a `TemplateBinding` to `Content` inside the template.

Comment: do you have any example on how to use Tag?

Comment: @djoxmccloud: The same way you use `Content`, you bind it to your property, and inside the template you bind to the `Tag`.

Comment: So what i do is : <Control Template="{StaticResource onoffValue1}" Tag="{Binding BootSector, Mode=TwoWay}"/> and in the template i use {Binding Tag, Mode=TwoWay} . But this doesn't work

Comment: As i said in the answer, you need a `TemplateBinding` inside, or a binding with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`

Comment: Ok I see. I read the doc here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx but it seems that TemplateBinding is in fact the opposite of what i want to do. It sets a property from the template to the control. Or i want to do the other way which is providing the template the property it has to modify

Comment: It goes both ways, if you bind to the `Content` of the `ContentControl` and said content is modified this change will propagate **into** the template.